# System time keeps changing

Tags: 10.04, time

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 10.04 with Windows 7, which I setup using Wubi. After logging in to the system, I noticed the time at the top panel is wrong and I changed it to the correct time. But as it turns out the problem does not stop there. The time keep changing and today (31th October) I fixed the time twice, but after few minutes it shows a wrong time again. Even the date is wrong. (Shows 1st November) What maybe wrong with the system?

Comment: How far off is the time in hours?  Is your clock set to UTC or localtime?  Does Windows 7 have a time issue?

Comment: time is off approximately about 25 hrs. And clock is set to local time. Now it's time 10.22 AM, 31 October but clock shows it 12.53 AM, 1 November. No Windows 7 does not have any time issues.

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/a/1319582/369618](https://askubuntu.com/a/1319582/369618) if all this failed please see my answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set timezone for country with daylight savings time. Today was winter time change at 3:00 local time to 2:00 local time. Try set correct timezone for your country, or switch off NTP syncronization.

To switch off:
System - Administration - Date and time, then press lock button, enter your password, and select **Manual** from dropdown box.

Comment: How can I switch off NTP synchronization?

Comment: You don't want to switch off NTP