# Ubuntu keeps resetting time to -3 hours

Tags: date

I have a dual boot system with Win 7 / Ubuntu 13.04. For some reason, Ubuntu resets the system time to -3 hours regardless of timezone settings. I thought that this was UTC problem, but the problem persists regardless of what is set in /etc/default/rcS.

```
# assume that the BIOS clock is set to UTC time (recommended)
UTC=no
```

If I check the timezone with date +%Z it states

```
UTC
```

However, when using the graphical user interface to check the timezone it shows that I'm in the right timezone.

Date gives me

```
pe 9.8.2013 13.51.52 +0000
```

While hwclock is the correct time

```
pe  9. elokuuta 2013 16.52.03  -0.516733 sekuntia
```

Ubuntu seems to set the BIOS time to wrong time. This happens on every boot, even after I've manually changed the time. Windows 7 does not have this problem. I could not find duplicates or solutions beyond the UTC settings.

The system is set to manual time and is not updating it from the internet. I've already tried that but it seems that it never updates so I'm stuck in the wrong time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does time change in Ubuntu after installing Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90504/why-does-time-change-in-ubuntu-after-installing-windows)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clock time is off on dual boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this, change time to **manually** instead of **Automatically from the internet**

[image]

[image]

Try this:

```
Remove/Purge ntp
Remove/Purge ntpdate
Install ntpdate
set UTC=yes in /etc/default/rcS
reboot
sudo ln -f -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Helsinki /etc/localtime
```

Comment: That is an excellent advice, except that it was already set to manual. Sorry for not mentioning it in the post. Any other suggestions? Edit: Wouldn't that also set it to the right time, in case the time zone was right? (It is, but it is not updating to the right time.)

Comment: Manual will not update from the net.  Once its set, it will not update.  Try changing the BIOS battery.

Comment: If the BIOS battery was done there would be other symptoms and it would not reset to current time -3. Also, there would also be problems in Windows, not just Ubuntu.

Comment: My mistake.  I did not see that about Windows.  What time zone are you in?  Do you have NTP installed?

Comment: It is. ntpdate -q gives me `10 Aug 10:01:19 ntpdate[5191]: no servers can be used, exiting`.

Comment: What is your time zone?

Comment: Europe/Helsinki. Seems that some parts of the system use UTC time and some get the time zone right.

Comment: See new info in my answer.

Comment: `$ ntpq -pn` try to put the output of the following command.

Comment: Reinstalling ntp and setting time settings to UTC seemed to fix the issue. Checking time from the Windows side showed it to be in -3 hours now, so it must be running local time. At least now all of different Linux-clocks agree with each other. Thank you for the help, @Mitch.

Comment: I changed Linux to local time and now I seem to have two operating systems in sync and in correct time.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are in a timezone 3 hours separate from UTC, and Windows and Linux are disagreeing about what time should be stored in the BIOS.

Linux stores time as UTC in the BIOS clock.

Windows stores time as local time.

So whenever you boot Windows, it resets the BIOS clock to local time, Linux loads it and assumes it's UTC.

I was under the impression that the Ubuntu installer would detect Windows and set Linux to compromise by using local time in the BIOS... but this may not be true, or may not have happened correctly.

There are two solutions :

- Set Windows to use UTC in the BIOS clock

This apparently has some caveats for "professional" usage but might be satisfactory from a user POV.

https://superuser.com/questions/185773/does-windows-7-support-utc-as-bios-time

- Set Linux to use local time in the BIOS clock

Set the UTC setting in `/etc/default/rcS` to "no" (on Ubuntu)

Comment: It would be helpful if you read the problem before answering. In my question I explicitly stated that **I thought that this was UTC problem, but the problem persists regardless of what is set in /etc/default/rcS.**

Answer (score 0):

This question is really old, but the answer that worked for me isn't listed so here it goes:

In the terminal:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

and then to check that it was successful:

```
timedatectl
```

It should give you a warning, because it is not preferred. You should see a line that reads RTC in local TZ:yes

Answer (score 0):

i am not a programmer . i failed in all the above steps. i have a dual boot with ubuntu 16.04 and genuine windows 10 (which is used rarely once in a month)

Here is what i did
in windows i disabled setting time and time zone automatically and asked to update from internet.windows date issue got solved but ubuntu showed wrong time when i tried to update automatically from net. then i installed

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

and time got corrected but was not showing in boot

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
```

finally solved that too.

now linux gurus can explain in detail what i did. For those who just want to get things running i feel this will help. I found all these from other questions and solved answers ok. so thanks to all of them again.

i discovered that i have to keep repeating these steps to keep clock healthy. Any help on finding a permanant solution?

Comment: What you basically did is that you told Ubuntu to enable the `ntp` service which periodically syncs your machine's clock with the internet. `ntp` stands for "Network Time Protocol". It's exactly the same thing you did in Windows, but instead of using the UI, you used the command line.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. Wish more of your kind where here lol