# Time zone is Kolkatta, India

Tags: dual-boot

On my system, the time zone is set to Kolkatta, India, but it is not showing the correct time on the clock, it's 5:30 hour behind actual time. In **System Settings** if default system country is US, even after Kolkatta, India has been selected, the time remains behind by 5:30 hour.

Can anyone suggest what I should do?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/330607/ubuntu-keeps-resetting-time-to-3-hours/330727#330727), see if it helps.

Comment: Check the time in your BIOS.

Comment: Are you dual booting? Windows and Ubuntu might be conflicting over the BIOS time (Ubuntu thinks BIOS time is UTC). See the first comment on how to fix this.